# Strange mysql_fetch_array output

Tags: php, mysql

My code is:

```
$query = "SELECT a.hash, a.full, a.partial, a.servers, a.lastupd, b.full, b.partial, b.servers, b.lastupd FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b WHERE a.hash='".$hashcode."' AND a.hash=b.hash;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

then I perform a

```
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

And I get this weird output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => blah
    [hash] => blah
    [1] => 1,1,1
    [full] => 0,1
    [2] => 1,2,1
    [partial] => 4,2
    [3] => srv1,srv2,srv3
    [servers] => srv2,srv3
    [4] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [lastupd] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [5] => 0,1
    [6] => 4,2
    [7] => srv2,srv3
    [8] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
)
```

Why there's data repetition for `b` table and doesn't create an associative array with keys `a.*` and `b.*`?

**Note:** the timestamps set to 0 are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because mysql_fetch_array returns both associative and numeric array. Use mysql_fetch_assoc, if you only need associative array.

(By the way, mysql is deprecated, [read about using mysqli or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php))

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array but just with the `a.hash` and the data from `b` table. Do I need to improve my query? How do I get data from `a` table too?

Comment: Yes, you have to have different aliases if in table a you have column FULL, then you need to rename table b column to FULLB (just an example).  b.full AS 'fullb' and so on